# Commence key press collection contingent on sound duration

Tags: duration, psychopy

I am implementing an experiment in Psychopy in which I am designing a same-different discrimination task comparing two sounds that are of variable duration (sound_1, sound_2) played in succession with an interval of 0.5 s in between. Now I have managed to start sound_1 at 0.0 and sound_2 at 0.5 s after the end of sound_1 using "$sound_1.getDuration() + 0.5"; however, I want to get a key press response with the RT measured from the end of sound_2 on; I tried start time "$sound_1.getDuration() + 0.5 + sound_2.getDuration()", however the keypress is already functional during the presentation of sound_2 and RTs appear to be too long as compared with usual RTs observed for this kind of task. Does anyone know how to obtain the accurate onset for measuring RTs here?

Btw my question is similar, however not fully answered by the following thread:
[variable stimuli duration but two kinds of fixed ISI in PsychoPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064222/variable-stimuli-duration-but-two-kinds-of-fixed-isi-in-psychopy)

Comment: Are you using pure code (Coder) or Builder with a Code component?

Comment: I'm assuming this is in Builder. @lucieg 's solution *should* work. Try some debugging by inserting a code component and put something like this in the "every routine" tab: `print(str(sound_1.getDuration() + 0.5 + sound_2.getDuration() )` and check if the values match watch you expect.

Comment: Yes, this was done in Builder and thanks for the suggestion to check the values this way and it gave me the exact sum for sound_1+sound_2+0.5 which I have set as onset time for my keyboard response. However, I am nonetheless not confident that response times are measured from the end of sound_2 on given that keyboard responses are functional already all along sound_2. Hence I now try a workaround in setting the keyboard response to 0 and afterwards subtracting the duration of the sounds plus 0.5s. If you know any better way to resolve this issue I would be really grateful. Many thanks again!